# Cloud sql down and required restart

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am using Google CloudSQL and the instance is down for the first time today. Can I find out the reason why in the logs, etc.?

This has happened during high load. I believe CloudSQL should be able to recover automatically. Do I need to set up something for auto-recovery?

Answer (score 0):

You should expect occasional CloudSQL instance restarts due to [maintenance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#maintenancerestart), etc. There is no detailed information available in the logs at the moment.

And yes, CloudSQL instances should be able to auto-recover in a reasonable amount of time (up to a few minutes).

Comment: the problem is that its not power up even after 4 hours and the status indicate as running. I try to use IPv4 to access and its still fail. The only way to make it work is restart it.... I have tried with D0 and D2 instance and both tend to fail with high traffic with 4 instances (rapid select)

Comment: @KennyKoay, such long unavailability is not normal and should be investigated with Google Cloud Support.